# How do I install firestarter on ubuntu 22.04.1?

Tags: software-installation, firewall

I use this distro, and I've tried sudo install but it says that the package was not found.
Tried through synaptic and also not found.
Has it been discontinued?

2-Is there a better front-end firewall?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The note on [the Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firestarter) is pretty ominous:

> Although Firstarter is fully functional, active development ended in 2005 with version 1.0.3. The latest version is 1.0.3-11. The official website and documentation (updated last August 2012) is [here](https://fs-security.com).

Clicking the "here" link points to a parked domain page. The project is most certainly abandoned at this point.

So, to answer your question: you *don't* install FireStarter. You use something different

Comment: He looked good to me.
Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

By default you probably already have UFW (uncomplicated Firewall) already installed on your system.

But if you are uncertain, you can install it with the following commands

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

sudo apt install ufw -y

enable with: sudo systemctl enable ufw --now

Verify status with systemctl status ufw

enable UFW with sudo ufw enable
```

[reference](https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-enable-configure-ufw-firewall-on-ubuntu-22-04/)

Once installed on your system and working, install the GUI front end `Firewall Configuration` from ubuntu software.

This front end makes it very easy to configure the tool as you require.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Ufw is good.
What caught my attention in firestarter is that it monitors the network, it's really sad that a good project doesn't go forward.